# ERROR StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - TCP connection failure in session _system_: Transport failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a web application about websocket, but when I use spring websockets and tomcat 8 over stomp and rabbitmq 3.2.4, the server seemed to have some problem, its log was full of this kind of errors:

```
2016-10-19 18:47:20 ERROR StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - TCP connection failure in session _system_: Transport failure: Connection reset by peer
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:118)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-10-19 18:47:25 ERROR StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - TCP connection failure in session _system_: Transport failure: Connection reset by peer
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:118)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-10-19 18:47:30 ERROR StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - TCP connection failure in session _system_: Transport failure: Connection reset by peer
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:118)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-10-19 18:47:33 INFO  WebSocketMessageBrokerStats - WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[1 sessions, 127.0.0.1:5672 (not available), processed CONNECT(1)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2016-10-19 18:47:35 ERROR StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - TCP connection failure in session _system_: Transport failure: Connection reset by peer
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:118)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:651)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:574)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:488)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:450)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My spring-websockets is 4.3.0.Release and my spring-amqp and spring-rabbit is 1.6.3.Release.
I didn't even have a SockJS client. This error was found as soon as the tomcat was started. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `3.2.4` is enough old Broker. Try to upgrade to the latest. Plus be sure that STOMP plugin is started on the broker.

Comment: I've upgraded the rabbitmq and its stopm plugin to version 3.6.5, but the tomcat startup log error is just as before...@ArtemBilan

Comment: Are you really sure that STOMP plugin is started? `rabbitmq-plugins list`

Comment: I've solved the problem, I set the wrong port in my configuration...@ArtemBilan Thanks for your favor!

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution. The rabbitmq stomp document says in default situations it will listen on port 61613, and correspondingly the spring stomp will connect to localhost:61613 by default. But I set the port to 5672 in configuration. How silly:).

Answer (score 1):

In k8s-rabbitmq-service.yaml expose these ports.

```
---
  ports:
  - name: ampq-port
    port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5672
  - name: management-port
    port: 15672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15672
  - name: mqtt-port
    port: 61613
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 61613
```

In k8s-rabbitmq-deployment.yaml expose these ports.

```
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5672
      name: port5672
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 15672
      name: port15672
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 61613
      name: port61613
      protocol: TCP
```

then try to run the other ms which is showing this error.

Basically, you have to change port 5672 to 61613